# Showing number of helpful flags in user profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, helpful-flags

I know the risks in showing the flagging history of an user.

But, we can show the number of helpful flags of an user to others. I can't find the no. of helpful flags of any user in SO. Lastly, I saw some users' helpful flags count, but they were the nominees for the moderator election.

How can I find the number of helpful flags made by any users?

---

**EDIT**

If hiding the helpful flag count is by design, what is the reason behind hiding that from others?

Even, we have three badges for helpful flag count to show others, in which range(0-1-80-500-) the flag count of user is laid.

Comment: Just wondering, but why would you want to see the number of helpful flags for each user anyway? Not sure what it buys you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reasoning behind hiding the flag count of other users is a way of protecting users from spite down-votes and other petty *"retaliations"*. Pretty much the same reason as to why you don't really see who down-votes you, nor can you check the profile of whomever you suspect and check their DV-count of that day; it'll just show the total number of votes of that day at best.

The difference between the two is that voting can (and should) be seen as a positive action towards you (the receiver of that vote): if it's an upvote, you've done a good job. If it's a down-vote, you can learn something or you have to edit your post.

Flagging is notifying the moderators that a user is not welcome, is spamming, trolling, insulting, etc. things that a spotty teenager might refer to as *"snitching"*. Knowing that you can do this annonymously is key for this system to work.

As far as the badges go: Having a rough idea on how many flags a given user has raised is not the same as knowing exactly how many, why and when.

Comment: Well in that case, why now hide the users who closed a question too?

Comment: @JerryDodge: because users that are able to close questions usually have more rep than those who posted the closed quesion (most of the time, thos users can't even down-vote). That, and the "close-voters" tend to give feedback, referring to the FAQ _and_ there are five of them... closing a question because it's posting on the wrong site doesn't _"piss people off"_ as much as flagging someone as being "not welcome"

Comment: Now, I found the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can't view others *helpful flag* count. You can only view your own in your profile.

An election is an exception. The *helpful flag* count helps deciding how much a user participates in moderation.