# Where can I find the total number of flags (helpful/not helpful)?

Tags: discussion, flags, flag-history

From the post [Showing number of helpful flags in user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175296/showing-number-of-helpful-flags-in-user-profile), I can see comment/answer that we can only see the flags in our own profile and not others. Also it is available in our profile section.

The reason why i am asking is because, going through the badges section, I can see 3 moderation badges:

1. [Marshall](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal)
2. [Deputy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1002/deputy)
3. [Citizen Patrol](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol)

Where can I see the list of flags that I cast and how useful they were? Please note that I am not talking about upvotes/downvotes.

Update :

As per @Servy's comments i can see a detailed list through the flag-summary link. But it still doesnt show actually a simple count like :

- Total Flags : 100
- Helpful Flags : 50
- Non-Helpful : 50

Hope i am more clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "helpful flags" link on your profile:

> [image]

In your case, the link is:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1046934

Answer (score 2):

The summary at the right of your flags page (reached by clicking the number of helpful flags on your profile once it is nonzero) tells you all you need to know. Here's mine for the Workplace:

[image]

You might have to hand-add your comment flags into the total: I forget if they count or not.

The reason I chose the Workplace is that my flagging history is fairly recent there. Individual totals used not to be available. My SO total looks like this:

[image]

This means that 1108 flags were cast "in the old days" and there's no record of whether they were helpful or not. (Flag weight used to matter more than number of flags and I believe I got Marshall on flag weight.)