# Should we have an ability to see others' consecutive days?

Tags: discussion, consecutive-days

I ran into a user whose next badge was "Fanatic":

> [image]

This clearly reveals his/her consecutive days. Should they really be displayed to everyone. They weren't visible to other users earlier; I guess there was a reason for it which has gone now?

Comment: Does anyone actually care about this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249981/should-the-number-of-helpful-flags-be-public-to-anyone

Comment: @Shog9 not me, I am here to contribute questions and answers - this seems, well, kind of social-media-ish

Comment: I mean, I get why you care about your own - there's a badge. But what does it matter if anyone else can/can't see this?

Comment: I can only think of your manager but I guess the profile by it self is a big give-away...

Comment: @Shog9 I care. It's one thing to display a log of my activity — it's visible anyway if you look — but I dislike having my *passive* behavior exposed like this. I'd prefer not to expose the “last visited” date on my profile either, convenient though it may sometimes be. When I visited a site and how often is my own business.

Comment: @Gilles I agree with you about this, and the "last visited" too. Also, can you or someone tell me what happens if we skip a day? I'm working towards this badge so I don't want to test it! Does the system just automatically default to a different badge I'm closer to?

Comment: @Sue That's quite a different question; however no, if you chosen this badge, the system won't switch you to another one until you earn this badge. But your progress would become 1/100.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see no harm in it. I feel the number of helpful flags is more private than this, and you can see that already.

You can already see when someone was last online, you can see [very detailed what someone did on a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=activity). So if you want to know, you can already mine it very easy. There is no point in hiding this.

If you don't like this, set your next badge to something else.

Comment: Accepting as seems this discussion is long over.