# Where did the "helpful flags" go?

Tags: support, status-completed, profile-page, helpful-flags

I just noticed that I can no longer see the number of helpful flags on other users' profiles. They used to be shown for all users (only clickable when someone is viewing their own profile). However, they're only shown to me when I'm viewing my profile now:

[image: The number of helpful flags is shown on my own Stack Overflow profile]

But not on other users' profiles:

[image: The number of helpful flags is not shown on Jon Skeet's Stack Overflow profile] [image: The number of helpful flags is not shown on rene's Meta Stack Exchange profile]

I'm not sure exactly when this started but they definitely were still shown after the [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372049) announcement.

AFAICT, there was no announcement about hiding this information and searching for "helpful flags" didn't return any relevant recent posts.

If this is not a bug, what was the reason behind this change? And why was it not announced seeing that it's not a trivial change?

Comment: Already reported on MSO and [tag:status-review]: [The number of helpful flags has disappeared](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415113/4642212).

Comment: [Prior discussion on having this info be public](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249981/377214). Do note that at the time, this number was private; it wasn't made public until later that year.

Comment: Prior conversation in [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9099732#9099732), and [my comment (here) to a Dev about this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page#comment1249695_372049).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The number of helpful flags was placed behind a conditional that only showed it if you were viewing your own profile and/or are a moderator. For what it's worth, this was unintentional. There were many nested conditionals in the Activity view and the display of this specific stat was lost in the refactor shuffle.

We've shipped out a fix to this, so helpful flags are visible to everyone once again. Thanks for reporting the bug!